# MongoDB connection failed with apache Storm - java

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-storm

I have a problem with my Apache Storm application, I am a beginner.
In particular,when I try to connect one bolt to a MongoDB, after the submit of the topology.
I have one spout that emits random values (just to test) and one bolt to insert them in a MongoDB. The problem is that when the spout starts to emit the MongoDB- Bolt fails in execution. 
I catched this exception run time for the bolt:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoClient at         bolts.MongoInsertBolt.prepare(MongoInsertBolt.java:29) at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$fn__5707.invoke(executor.clj:757) at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__545.invoke(util.clj:477) at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.MongoClient at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) [...]
```

This problem persists **only in cluster-mode**. 
In local-mode it works perfectly, I can access to MongoDB, submit queries etc.
This is my bolt implementation.

Thanks in advance.

```
    private MongoClient mongoClient; 
    private  DBCollection table;

    public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context,OutputCollector collector) {

    this.collector = collector;
    this.mongoClient = new MongoClient("xxx.yyy.zzz.www",27020);
    mongoClient.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE);
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("DB_Storm");
    this.table = db.getCollection("storm_netflow");

}

public void execute(Tuple input) {

    String netflow = input.getStringByField("netpack");
    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
    document.put("id", netflow);
    this.table.insert(document);
    [...]
    this.mongoClient.close();
}
```

Comment: A single bolt is no valid topology... You need to have a spout, too. I am wondering who you can even submit it to a local/remote cluster?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't explain well the situation. I have one spout that emits random values (just for try) and one bolt to insert them in a MongoDB. The problem is that when the spout starts to emit the MongoDB- Bolt fails in execution. 
This morning I catched this exception run time for the bolt: NoClassDefFoundError:org.bson.Document [...]. But I already included Bson.jar.

Comment: Please update your question instead of answering in comment fields -- this keeps SO clear (nobody wants to read all the comments ;)). Did you double-check that the *content* of Bson.jar is copied into your topology jar that you submit to the cluster?

Comment: Ok, I  updated the question. Sorry, I am new here. Anyway, yes. I import Bson.jar but I have this problem also with the simple MongoClient. Can using Maven be a problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "import" -- I do not refer to Java's import statement. What is the content of your topology jar file? It must contain those classes. If you use maven, I assume that your topology jar is incomplete, ie, missing `org.bson.Document.class` -- there is a couple of questions in SO about Storm and correct packaging of the topology jar...

Comment: Hi Matthias, finally I solved my problem. I forgot to include all the libraries in the main folder storm/lib. This procedure on each machine of the cluster. Anyway, thanks for you time. Cheers

Comment: Yep. This does work, too.